# Count differences between different versions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json field named diff in my dataframe which looks like this:

```
diff": {
    "paths": {
      "added": [
        "/login/token"
      ]
    },
    "endpoints": {
      "added": [
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "path": "/login/token"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This is how it occurs in the csv:

```
{'paths': {'added': ['/login/token']}, 'endpoints': {'added': [{'method': 'POST', 'path': '/login/token'}]}}
```

The idea here is that I want to generate a count of the differences, suppose here are essentially two fields in which modifications take place, `paths` and `endpoints`. I want to count the total number of fields/subfields which undergo a change. Every difference corresponds to its `commmitdate` and its `info_version` field. So sometimes on the same day, we have 2 version changes as well.

An example of sub fields is the changes within the title and description of the information field

```
info:{
   title:
    description:
}
```

I haven't worked with such a use case before,so I am not sure how will this work around. Also, there has to be some classification for all the changes occuring: added, removed, modified etc( I am trying to figure this out). Any ideas/suggestions on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: _I want to count the total number of fields/subfields which undergo a change_ A change **from** what **to** what, exactly?  From one row to another in the dataframe?  From one dataframe to another?

Comment: the changes are within the operations, so in the json where i have mentioned added , it tells what was added, similarly for what was removed. Since this is an openapi dataset, for every api at every date, it undergoes change in any one of its field

Comment: So if under the diff field, i see three fields mentioned: paths, endpoints and info. the diff count is 3. That means 3 parameters underwent some change(which can be anything). But the issue is sometimes some of these parameters have changes in their own sub parameters, like `info` fields carries metadata about the api. It can have name,title,description fields like these. But if I go straight to count the nested elements in the column, that will also add the `added`, `removed` fields as well, which I dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now I could come up with this solution, which solves the problem partially( as sub fields have not been considered, just elements in the json file). I have used `iterrows` to count the number of elements present in each instance of `diff`

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df['num_fields'] = 0

# We iterate over rows and count the number of elements in each 'diff' instance
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    diff_dict = ast.literal_eval(row['diff'])
    num_fields = len(diff_dict.keys())
    df.at[i, 'num_fields'] = num_fields
```